# Disable/modify readthedocs shorturl

Tags: read-the-docs

I've built a containerized readthedocs installation.  Happy with it so far, however I see that it builds short urls on the project page.  Unfortunately the short url's don't exist in DNS, so don't link anywhere.  For example, they appear as `<project>.readthedocs.mydomain.com`

Trawling through the admin portal and rtd docs, I can't see where they are configured and I haven't found a way to either modify the shorturl to a different format or disable the shorturl.  Has anyone else had this issue, perhaps have a solution they could share?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `USE_SUBDOMAIN` setting may be what you're looking for. See [Interesting Settings](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html) in the docs for more info.